# Equivalent function for completefunc in SPSERVICES

Tags: sharepoint, attachment, spservices

I am trying to implement completefunc in SPSERVICES for the purpose of file attachments. I have completed the function using completefunc which is successfull. But actually completefunc is not required. So,I tried by removing completefunc and I am facing the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: av.completefunc is not a function
```

My code is:

```
$().SPServices( {        
        operation: "Attachment",
        listName: ,//name of the list
        listItemID: ,//list item id
        fileName: attachmentInformation[attachmentName + '_NAME'],
        attachment: attachment,
        async: false,
        debug: true,
        completefunc:null
    } );
```

I tried removing completefunc as per the requirment and I am facing the above error.
Please suggest me a way of doing this by removing completefunc

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just deleting the `completefunc` line?

```
$().SPServices( {        
    operation: "Attachment",
    listName: ,//name of the list
    listItemID: ,//list item id
    fileName: attachmentInformation[attachmentName + '_NAME'],
    attachment: attachment,
    async: false,
    debug: true
} );
```